# Dropzone not works when push a new element with jQjuery

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js

I have a form to create an Article. I used Dropzone to manage upload files. The user might need to add new Dropzone more than one. So, Everything is working but accept when I tried to push more Dropzone through jQuery. I think Dropzone not start again.

```
$('.btn-add').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var element = '';
    element = '<div class="article-item ui-state-default">'
    + '<div class="dropzone dropzone-previews multiple-upload>'
    + '</div>';
    ('#sortable').append(element);
});



Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
   $('div.multiple-upload').dropzone({
        acceptedFiles : '.png, .gif, .jpg',
        dictCancelUpload : '',
        dictCancelUploadConfirmation : '',
        maxFilesize : 100,
        addRemoveLinks : true,
        init: function () {
             thisDropzone = this;
             var extractEle = thisDropzone.element.className;
             var extractClass = extractEle.split(' ');
             var obj = $('.' + extractClass[3]);
             var filename = $(obj).find('.media-item').val();
             var file_array = [];
             if (filename !== '') {
                 file_array = filename.split(',');
             }

             for (var index = 0; index < file_array.length; index++) {
                  var mockFile = {name: file_array[index], size: 75};
                  thisDropzone.options.addedfile.call(thisDropzone, mockFile);
                  thisDropzone.options.thumbnail.call(thisDropzone, mockFile, BASE_URL + '/articles/' + file_array[index]);
             }
           },
           url: BASE_URL + '/writer/articles/upload'
 });
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Do you want to add a new dropzone with that same configuration every time the button is clicked?

Comment: Yes, I am. So do you have idea?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a dropzone every time you click the button, then you should add the `.dropzone()` method inside the click event, for the div element you just created, also you have some errors in the `var element` string.

Here an example:

```
$('.btn-add').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var element = '';
    element = '<div class="article-item ui-state-default">'
    + '<div class="dropzone dropzone-previews multiple-upload">'
    + '</div></div>';
    $('#sortable').append(element);


    $('div.multiple-upload').last().dropzone({
        acceptedFiles : '.png, .gif, .jpg',
        dictCancelUpload : '',
        dictCancelUploadConfirmation : '',
        maxFilesize : 100,
        addRemoveLinks : true,
        init: function () {
            thisDropzone = this;
            var extractEle = thisDropzone.element.className;
            var extractClass = extractEle.split(' ');
            var obj = $('.' + extractClass[3]);
            var filename = $(obj).find('.media-item').val();
            var file_array = [];
            if (filename !== '') {
                file_array = filename.split(',');
            }

            for (var index = 0; index < file_array.length; index++) {
                var mockFile = {name: file_array[index], size: 75};
                thisDropzone.options.addedfile.call(thisDropzone, mockFile);
                thisDropzone.options.thumbnail.call(thisDropzone, mockFile, BASE_URL + '/articles/' + file_array[index]);
            }
        },
        url: BASE_URL + '/writer/articles/upload'
    });
});
```

Just note that in this particular case there is no need to add the  `Dropzone.autoDiscover = false` since there isn't any dropzone element when the page loads.